# Android button does not respond to OnClickListener:

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, httprequest, onclicklistener

This is my first post here... I am learning android programming to make an app. I have tried to follow tutorials online to first get my app to communicate with a server I've set up to login users from a sql database.
However in my login button doesnt seem to do anything.
Here is the LoginActivity:

```
    package com.tazo.zegga.app;

import ...


public class LoginActivity extends PlusBaseActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    String response = null;
    TextView  txt_Error;

    public void login (View view) {
        EditText txt_uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText txt_pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        String uname=txt_uname.getText().toString();
        String pwd=txt_pwd.getText().toString();
        UserLoginTask task = new UserLoginTask(uname, pwd);
        task.execute(uname, pwd);
    }
        public final static String EXTRA_RESULT = "com.tazo.zegga.result";

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mEmailLoginFormView;
    private SignInButton mPlusSignInButton;
    private View mSignOutButtons;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();


            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        mEmailLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.email_login_form);
        mSignOutButtons = findViewById(R.id.plus_sign_out_buttons);
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    public void attemptLogin() {

        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }


        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        UserLoginTask task = new UserLoginTask(email,password);
        task.execute(email, password);




    }
    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }



    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;


        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0] ));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1] ));
            String res = null;
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.1.50/zegga/v1/index.php/login", postParameters);
                res=response.toString();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                txt_Error.setText(e.toString());
            }
            return res;
        }//close doInBackground


        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
            Intent intentLogin = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intentLogin.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, result);
            startActivity(intentLogin);

        }


        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: removed the code related to the G+ signin... Thanks to CodeMagic for pointing out much of my code was not needed here...

Comment: Way too much code, my friend! I don't see your `signIn()` method but I might have gotten lost in everything else.

Comment: I have used and edited the login activity from android studio... I'm sorry but I don't know what code to remove to make it easier to understand

Comment: Usually the code which is not working/failing. So, for example, all of the import statements aren't often needed, extra methods which have nothing to do with the current problem, etc... All of that is just extra "noise" for us to sift through and we can always politely ask for more code if we think it is needed. I **still** don't see that method that should be called. You could possibly make that more visible.

Comment: I have edited it... hope it is alright now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the OnClickListener of your mPlusSignInButton button you have called signIn() method. However, there is no such method.

If you want the user login through Google+, instead of using your signIn button you should use Google+ signIn button.

Please refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) for implementing Google+ sign-in button in your Android app.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. the G+ signin button is working, it is my own email sign in button that is not...